# How do I finish this SQL Server 2008 query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need a SQL 2008 query that returns all consumers who have > 1 userfield record WITH THE SAME USERFIELDUUID linked to them -- in other words, all those consumers who have duplicate userfield records.

Relevant fields in `CONSUMER_USER_FIELD` record:

```
CONSUMER_USER_FIELD_UUID - primary key
USERFIELD_UUID
CONSUMER_UUID
```

Relevant fields in `CONSUMER` record:

```
CONSUMER_UUID - primary key
```

Relevant fields in `USER_FIELD` record:

```
USERFIELD_UUID - primary key
CONSUMER_UUID
FIELD_NAME
PROMPT
```

I have the code that finds all consumers who have >1 CONSUMER_USER_FIELD (CUF) record.  I'm just having trouble with the "and the same userfield_uuid is on > 1 of those CUF records" part.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT c.consumer_uuid 
FROM   consumer c 
       INNER JOIN consumer_user_field cuf 
               ON cuf.consumer_uuid = c.consumer_uuid 
WHERE  1 < (SELECT count(user_field_uuid) 
            FROM   consumer_user_field cuf2 
            WHERE  cuf2.consumer_uuid = c.consumer_uuid)
```

Am I on the right track?  Do I just need a HAVING clause now?

Comment: I think this question is fine, why is everyone voting to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT C.*
FROM
   dbo.Consumer C
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.Consumer_User_Field CUF
      WHERE C.Consumer_UUID = CUF.Consumer_UUID
      GROUP BY CUF.USERFIELD_UUID
      HAVING Count(*) >= 2
   )
;
```

P.S. To anyone who wants to complain that you can't do `SELECT *` with a `GROUP BY`: you can inside an `EXISTS` clause. Please try it yourself before posting. :)

You could also do it this way:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM
   dbo.Consumer C
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT CUF.Consumer_UUID
      FROM dbo.Consumer_User_Field CUF
      GROUP BY
         CUF.Consumer_UUID,
         CUF.USERFIELD_UUID
      HAVING Count(*) >= 2
   ) U ON C.Consumer_UUID = U.Consumer_UUID
;
```

And yet another idea:

```
SELECT C.*
FROM
   dbo.Consumer C
WHERE
   EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         dbo.Consumer_User_Field CUF
      WHERE
         C.Consumer_UUID = CUF.Consumer_UUID
         AND EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM dbo.Consumer_User_Field CUF2
            WHERE
               CUF.Consumer_UUID = CUF2.Consumer_UUID
               AND CUF.USERFIELD_UUID <> CUF2.USERFIELD_UUID
         )
   )
;
```

These are, from a logical perspective, equivalent queries. They may perform differently--you should try them and see which one works best. If you do, would you please let me know?

Comment: THANK YOU, ErikE.  I didn't understand what was wrong with my question, either.  You've helped immensely; this query worked perfectly.